Classify stationary points of $f(x) = 2x_1^3 - 6x_2^2 + 3x_1 ^2x_2$
Given be the function $f(x) = 2x_1^3 - 6x_2^2 + 3x_1 ^2x_2$. 
I would like to compute and classify all stationary points $x^*$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Function:} \ f( x) &  \begin{array}{l}
=2x_{1}^{3} -6x_{2}^{2} +3x_{1}^{2} x_{2}\\
\end{array}\\
\text{Gradient:} \ \nabla f &  \begin{array}{l}
=\begin{pmatrix}
f_{x_{1}}\\
f_{x_{2}}
\end{pmatrix} =3\cdotp \begin{pmatrix}
2x_{1} \cdotp ( x_{1} +x_{2})\\
x_{1}^{2} -4x_{2}
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{array}\\
\text{Hessian:} \ \nabla ^{2} f &  \begin{array}{l}
=\begin{pmatrix}
f_{x_{1}^{2}} & f_{x_{1} x_{2}}\\
f_{x_{2} x_{1}} & f_{x_{2}^{2}}
\end{pmatrix} =6\cdotp \begin{pmatrix}
2x_{1} +x_{2} & x_{1}\\
x_{1} & -2
\end{pmatrix}\\
\end{array}\\
\text{Stationary Points:} \ \nabla f\  &  \begin{array}{l}
=0\\
\end{array}\\
f_{x_{1}} & =6x_{1} \cdotp ( x_{1} +x_{2}) =0\\
 &  \begin{array}{l}
\rightarrow x_{1} =0,\ or\\
\rightarrow x_{1} +x_{2} =0\quad \rightarrow x_{1} =-x_{2}\\
\end{array}\\
x_{1} =0:\quad f_{x_{2}} & =3x_{1}^{2} -12x_{2}\\
 &  \begin{array}{l}
=3\cdotp 0^{2} -12x_{2}\\
\rightarrow x_{2} =0\\
\rightarrow \ sp_{1} =( 0,0)\\
\end{array}\\
x_{1} =-x_{2} :\quad f_{x_{2}} & =3x_{1}^{2} -12x_{2} =0\\
 &  \begin{array}{l}
=( -x_{2})^{2} -4x_{2}\\
=x_{2}^{2} -4x_{2}\\
=x_{2} -4\\
\rightarrow x_{2} =4\quad \rightarrow x_{1} =-4\\
\rightarrow sp_{2} =( -4,4)\\
\end{array}\\
\mathbf{x^{*}} & =\{\ ( 0,0) ,\ ( -4,4) \ \}\\
 &  \begin{array}{l}
f( 0,0) =0\\
f( -4,4) =-32\\
\end{array}
\end{align*}
There are two ways to classify/characterize stationary points:
- Classify SPs by Determinant:
  • Determinant: D = fₓₓ·fᵧᵧ - fₓᵧ²
  • Trace:       T = fₓₓ+fᵧᵧ
  • If D>0 and T>0 then: x* = local minimum.
  • If D>0 and T<0 then: x* = local maximum.
  • If D<0         then: x* = Saddle point.
  • If D≠0         then: x* = Non-degenerate point.
  • If D=0         then: x* = Degenerate point.

- Classify SPs by Eigenvalues:
  • H = Hessian Matrix ∇²f
  • If H≻0 (pos def λ>0), then x* = strict local minimum.
  • If H⪰0 (pos sem λ≥0), then x* =        local minimum.
  • If H≺0 (neg def λ<0), then x* = strict local maximum.
  • If H⪯0 (neg sem λ≤0), then x* =        local maximum.
  • Else:  ( in def λ∈ℝ), else x* = saddle point.

\begin{align*}
D\left( x^{*}\right) & =( f_{xx}) \cdotp ( f_{yy}) -( f_{xy}) ²\\
 & =( 2x_{1} +x_{2}) \cdotp ( -2) -( x_{1}) ²\\
 & \\
D( -4,4) & =( 2\cdotp ( -4) +4) \cdotp ( -2) -( -4) ²\ =\ -8\\
 & \rightarrow D< 0:\ \text{Saddle point}\\
 & \\
D( 0,0) & =( 2\cdotp 0+0) \cdotp ( -2) -( 0) ²\ =\ 0\\
 & \rightarrow D=0:\ \text{Degenerate point → Eigenvalue analysis required!}\\
 & \\
\det( H-\lambda \mathbb{1}) & =0\\
D( 0,0) & =6\cdotp \begin{pmatrix}
0-\lambda  & 0\\
0 & -2-\lambda 
\end{pmatrix} =0\\
 &  \begin{array}{l}
=( f_{xx} -\lambda ) \cdotp ( f_{yy} -\lambda ) -( f_{xy}) ²\\
=( 0-\lambda ) \cdotp ( -2-\lambda ) -( 0) ²\\
=( \lambda +0) \cdotp ( \lambda +2) =0\\
\rightarrow \mathbf{\lambda } =\{0,2\} \quad =\ \text{Eigenvalues of H}\\
\rightarrow \mathbf{\lambda } \geq 0\quad \rightarrow \text{local minimum}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
While we managed to correctly classify SP2 (-4,4) as a saddle point,
SP1 (0,0) seems not to be a local minimum, but a saddle point as well:

I tried to re-compute this example and feel like having the tunnel view.
Any tips/hints/links are highly appreciated!

The eigenvalues of the hessian matrix are ${0,-12}$, no? It's just a diagonal matrix.

In this case the tests you mentioned are inconclusive. (This is also mentioned in the wikipedia link you provided). To argue what type of stationary point the origin is, you can try a more "hands on" approach. You could try to see how $f$ changes by moving only in the $x$-direction at the origin.

What do you mean with $H>0$, $H<0$, ... for a matrix $H$?

@user408858 It means whether the matrix is positive/negative - semidefinite/definite.

Your tables are conflicting. That is the problem. By showing $D=0$ you already see that one of the eigenvalues has to be zero with the formula $D=\lambda_1\cdot \lambda_2$. This means, either minimum, maximum or saddlepoint without any further information.

By the way, you have a lot of computation mistakes: $6(-2-\lambda)\ne -12-\lambda$. Also $(\lambda+2)=0$ for $\lambda=-2$, not $\lambda=2$. Apart from that, the other eigenvalue should be $\lambda=-12$.

Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ denote the eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f$. Then, it holds
$$D=\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2,\quad T=\lambda_1+\lambda_2.$$
You clearly find, that one eigenvalue is equal to zero and therefore it could be either a minimum, maximum or saddle point, as it is written in the fourth point of the second partial derivative test.
